# UITableView Section not drawing correctly / EXC_Bad_Access when scrolled off screen

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

So I can't figure out why this extremely simple UITableView section is drawing incorrectly, and secondly when I attempt to scroll this sucker off screen it throws random errors, sometimes bad_access and other such green highlighted errors.

This is a picture of what exactly is happening on the device, and below is the code I am using first in the appDelegate to create the tableview cell's themselves. Thanks

**In the appDelegate**

```
SignUp *signup = [[SignUp alloc] initWithNibName:@"SignUp" bundle:nil];
signup.view.frame = self.window.frame;

[self.window addSubview:signup.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

**To Create the TableView**

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"EditableCell";

   EditableCell *editableCell = (EditableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

   if (editableCell == nil) {

       editableCell = [[EditableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];   
   }

   UITextField *cellTextField = [editableCell textFieldCell];

   cellTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
   cellTextField.delegate = self;


   return editableCell;
```

**The Error:**[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating your view controller, but never holding onto it with anything. As soon as your didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method exits, you'll lose your view controller and run into memory problems. Holding onto a view controllers view does not hold onto a view controller. Instead of adding the view directly to the window use:

```
self.window.rootViewController = signup;
```

This will both take ownership of the view and should set it's frame so you don't have to do so manually. You're currently setting the frame to the same frame of the window which is shoving it up under the status bar.

Comment: You, sir, are a true pal. Thanks so much. I have 1 other question though, if you don't mind: this view is meant to be a temporary sign-up/sign-in view for the app. Once the person signs up I'd like to close this view and bring up my next stack of views in a different navigation controller. Where would I add the code to do this? Would it be in SignUp but referencing the appDelegate? Again, thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem. If this view is just temporary, my personal preference is to set your root view controller to the permanent nav stack you mentioned and then present the signup view controller modally. Then when the user is done, they get a nice animation of it sliding off the bottom of the screen revealing the app.

Comment: Yea, that makes sense. Ok well you've been really helpful, thanks again!